# $K[[T]]$ is complete ring with respect to $M$-adic topology

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $K[[T]]=K[[t_1,\dots,t_n]]$ be the power series ring over a ring $K$ in $n$ variables and let $M=(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ be ideal of $K[[T]]$. Then show that $K[[T]]$ is a complete ring with respect to $M$-adic topology.

Comment: It is obvious that any Cauchy sequence has an unique limit. Maybe you're using a sophisticated definition of completeness?

Comment: I do not see your difficulty. If I recall correctly, this is a standard result you can find in any commutative algebra book.

Comment: @Bombyx mori tell me one book name